# Docker isn't running after sudo service docker start and can't uninstall

Tags: docker

I installed docker for ubuntu using the official documentation but when I attempted to start it using:

```js
$ sudo service docker start
$ sudo service docker status
```

I got a response that docker isn't running. I tried to uninstall the package but got:

```js
Removing docker-ce (5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping Docker: docker                                                                                              start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 2306: No such process
No process in pidfile '/var/run/docker-ssd.pid' found running; none killed.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--remove):
 installed docker-ce package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

I searched a lot of other similar questions but couldn't find anything that worked for me. I tried removing /var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-ce.prerm but that didn't change anything either. I am an absolute beginner for Linux so I would very much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these commands, don't know but need to say:

To get all installed docker packages you can run this command

sudo dpkg --list | grep docker

then to remove these packages

sudo dpkg -r --force-all [pastepackagesthatprinted]